# Does http_proxy automatically work in Linux for all applications?

Tags: c, linux, proxy, http-proxy

If I `export http_proxy`, then `curl` will use the proxy automatically. Is this because `curl` looks up `http_proxy` and setup proxy internally in the source code or it just automatically works? Seems many other applications support http_proxy automatically, so I think maybe http_proxy is handled by Linux??

I'm writing an application that needs to support proxy(http_proxy ENV), and wondering should I handle http_proxy in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because curl looks up http_proxy and setup proxy internally in the source code or it just automatically works?

`curl` get's the value of environment variable `http_proxy` in [curl/lib/url.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/18f044f19d26f2b6dcd41796966f488a62a1bdca/lib/url.c#L1580) and processes it. It does not work "automatically".

> I think maybe http_proxy is handled by Linux?

No, it is not. It is explicitly handled by curl.

> wondering should I handle http_proxy in the source code.

You can keep compatibility with other tools like `curl` and support `http_proxy` environment variable in your application.

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html

> libcurl respects the proxy environment variables named http_proxy, ftp_proxy, sftp_proxy etc. If set, libcurl will use the specified proxy for that URL scheme. So for a "FTP://" URL, the ftp_proxy is considered. all_proxy is used if no protocol specific proxy was set.
>
> Setting the proxy string to "" (an empty string) will explicitly disable the use of a proxy, even if there is an environment variable set for it.

Answer (score 0):

Running through a work proxy, I find it is not consistent. Many programs look for `http_proxy`, but others use their own config files. I'm not aware of any guidelines on which to use, and it depends on the library you are using to access the net.

If you are using `curl`, [the API `curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, char *proxy)` says](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html):

> libcurl respects the proxy environment variables named http_proxy, ftp_proxy, sftp_proxy etc. If set, libcurl will use the specified proxy for that URL scheme. So for a "FTP://" URL, the ftp_proxy is considered. all_proxy is used if no protocol specific proxy was set.
>
> If no_proxy (or NO_PROXY) is set, it is the exact equivalent of setting the CURLOPT_NOPROXY option.
>
> The CURLOPT_PROXY and CURLOPT_NOPROXY options override environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It should the curl read environment variables `http_proxy` and setup proxy, not the linux system.